# ¿Cómo sustituir el control de un formulario por uno del mismo tipo generado dinámicamente?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

no sé si he sido demasiado claro con el título así que disculparme si no ha sido así.
Pongo un ejemplo de a lo que me refiero, muy simple, pero imagino que será extensible a cualquier control de Windows Forms.
Creo un `textBox` en un formulario **"textBox1"**, ahora por código, instancio un `textBox` y a su propiedad `Text` le asigno el valor "prueba":

```
textBox cajaTextoDinamica = new textBox();
cajaTextoDinamica.Text = "prueba";
```

En mi cabeza, tenía sentido que si yo escribía: `textBox1 = cajaTextoDinamica;` el `textBox1` del formulario se substituiría por el generado dinámicamente, pero no es así.
Sin embargo aunque en el formulario no se muestre tal control, la propiedad `text` del `txtBox1` ahora tiene el valor "prueba" aunque no lo muestra.
Espero haberme explicado suficientemente bien y os agradecería que me dijerais que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Porque quieres hacer esto de esa forma, no es correcto el camino que explicas, hay otras formas de realizarlo, pero no se si entendi cual es el objetivo o contexto por el cual lo planteas de esa forma

Comment: No es un caso concreto, es básicamente aprendizaje. Me preguntaba si podía tener una clase en la que yo pudiera parametrizar el control generado dinámicamente y luego asignarlo a un control ya situado en el formulario.

Comment: Vas a tener que quitar el control actual y agregar el nuevo a la coleccion Controls del form (o del contenedor donde quieras poner), definiendo la porpiedad Location para que se ubique correctamente. Los componentes no se pisan porque despues no tienes un refresh que informe a la UI de esa actualizacion de referencia en memoria. No estoy seguro pero quizas si fuera WPF con xaml al tener INotifyPropertyChanged este tendria una forma de notificar del cambio, pero habria que probarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que planteas sí se puede hacer. No le encuentro mucho sentido a cambiar un control por otro del mismo tipo, pero como mencionas que se trata de aprendizaje, se me ocurre un caso hipotético que pudiera resolverse cambiando un control por otro.

Digamos que se requiere un formulario donde el usuario tiene que elegir la opción A o la opción B. Si elige la opción A, debe escribir una información en un TextBox, pero si elige la opción B, debe seleccionar un valor en un ComboBox.

Para resolverlo, ubicamos en el formulario un control Label que servirá para marcar la posición del lugar donde queremos que esté el control definitivo y le asignamos las siguientes propiedades:

- `AutoSize = false`, esto nos permitirá cambiarle el tamaño que servirá para asignarlo al control definitivo.
- `TabIndex` esta propiedad define el orden de recorrido de los controles cuando se pulsa la tecla tabulador.
- `Name = label1` aunque puede ser cualquier nombre.

La forma de reemplazar el control es la siguiente:

```
private void CrearTextBox()
{
    // Instancia el nuevo control y de una vez se inicializan las propiedades de interés
    var cajaTextoDinamica = new TextBox()
    {
        Text = "prueba",
        Location = label1.Location,
        TabIndex = label1.TabIndex,
        Size = label1.Size
    };

    // Esta instrucción elimina el control Label del formulario
    this.Controls.Remove(label1);

    // Esta instrucción agrega el nuevo control al formulario
    this.Controls.Add(cajaTextoDinamica);

}
```

Este ejemplo debería servir para reemplazar cualquier control. Ten en cuenta que es necesario agregar validaciones para asegurar que el control existe antes de eliminarlo o que no existe antes de agregarlo.
Por ejemplo:

```
// Ejemplo para validar que el control existe antes de eliminarlo
if (this.Controls.IndexOf(label1) >= 0)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(label1);
}
```